# Fonts & Color Themes for Xcode7

Tags: xcode, xcode7

Is there a way to install Themes on Xcode7.

I know that there are several themes available for Xcode. But, I am wondering if third party themes works on Xcode7?

I tried to copy the XYZ.dvtcolortheme into the directory ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/. Even though the theme shows up in the Xcode, I cannot see the changes in Fonts and Color after selecting the theme.

Any help?

Comment: concur that, upgraded Xcode 7 still keeps the custom themes, but when I try to install that into another new Xcode 7, the old method doesn't work

Comment: Try closing all projects of Xcode and quit completely. Relaunch it and select the theme again from Preferences, Font & Colors tab.

Comment: I agree with @bademi but if that doesn't work try restarting your computer (as all Genius Bar "genius's" say (; )

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing what @bademi and what @CoolPenguin said. Try to close out of Xcode and then restart your computer. If those don't work I recommend contacting whoever made the theme to see if they know what's up. Hope I helped!